# unit testing : mocking a service still causes the control to go inside of service(EasyMock)

Tags: java, oop, unit-testing, easymock

I want to test xyz function in UserServiceImpl, which has a service call to y.authenticateUser().
Even after mocking service class the control still goes into y.authenticateUser()  Does the
creation of object of Y in UserServiceImpl affect this?

```
public void testxyz(){
    User user1 = createUser("user1", "password", 1L);

    final Y y =  EasyMock.createMock(Y.class);
    final UserServiceImpl userService = new UserServiceImpl();
    final UserDAO userDao = EasyMock.createMock(UserDAO.class);
    ((BaseElementsService) userService).setUserDao(userDao);

    EasyMock.expect(y.authenticateUser(user1.getUsername(), user1.getPasswd())).andReturn(true);
    EasyMock.expect(userDao.findByUserName(user1.getUsername())).andReturn(user1);
    assertNotNull("User is null i.e not a valid user",user1);

    EasyMock.replay(y, userDao );
    assertEquals(userService.xyz(user1.getUsername(), user1.getPasswd()), user1);

    EasyMock.verify(y, userDao );
}


class UserServiceImpl {
    private final Y y = new y();

    public User xyz() {
        if( y.authenticateUser() ) {
            //code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Does the creation of object of Y in UserServiceImpl affect this?**

In short, yes.

Basically, you've created a mock Y object and then not used it within the execution of the code. When you call `xyz()` it is using the instance of Y that is created within the instance of `UserServiceImpl`

If you want to be able to use a mocked instance of Y, then you'll need to be able to set the instance of Y within the `UserServiceImpl` class. You could do this using a setter method, like you've done for the userDao. Or it might be nicer to have a constructor for these dependencies. (Keep in mind though you may need the no-args constructor, so you'll have to add that in too)

Here's how I'd do it:

```
class UserServiceImpl {
    private Y y = new y();

    public UserServiceImpl() {
        super();
    }

    public UserServiceImpl( final Y y, final UserDao userDao ) {
        super();
        this.y = y;
        setUserDao(userDao); //Or however you would set this....
    }

    public User xyz() {
        if( y.authenticateUser() ) {
            //code
        }
    }
}
```

Then within your test, you would do this:

```
public void testxyz(){
    User user1 = createUser("user1", "password", 1L);

    final Y y =  EasyMock.createMock(Y.class);
    final UserDAO userDao = EasyMock.createMock(UserDAO.class);

    final UserServiceImpl userService = new UserServiceImpl(y, userDao);

    EasyMock.expect(y.authenticateUser(user1.getUsername(), user1.getPasswd())).andReturn(true);
    EasyMock.expect(userDao.findByUserName(user1.getUsername())).andReturn(user1);
    assertNotNull("User is null i.e not a valid user",user1);

    EasyMock.replay(y, userDao );
    assertEquals(userService.xyz(user1.getUsername(), user1.getPasswd()), user1);

    EasyMock.verify(y, userDao );
}
```

Comment: On the technique you mentioned I get the follwoing error:N/A

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.wingu.elements.platform.account.UserServiceImpl.encodePassword(UserServiceImpl.java:298)
at com.wingu.elements.platform.account.UserServiceImpl.checkIfSamePassword(UserServiceImpl.java:679)
at com.wingu.elements.platform.account.UserServiceImpl.validateUser(UserServiceImpl.java:671)
at com.wingu.elements.platform.service.user.UserServiceTests.testValidateUserOnValidUserInput(UserServiceTests.java:83)

Comment: the function checkifSamePassword is called from inside of authenticateUser() and encodePassword is called from  checkIfSamePassword()....I have a question here. They are also called using some services...do I have to mock the services used inside of authenticateUser() also

Comment: Whatever services are used within your `xyz` method, you should mock those too. Keep in mind, that at the minute, you're mentioning methods and code that I haven't seen.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Can you suggest me any book where in I can learn about unit testing using EasyMock and also the code refactoring required for unit testing

Comment: No worries. I don't know any books on the subject of mocking and testing, but mocking is quite a common practice. It ultimately comes down to design, and [here is a good article](http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/unit-testing-with-junit-and-easymock.html) on Test Driven Design and unit testing using mocks.